# How to display the result of function called using object reference in c++

Tags: class, object, display, function-call

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
class LetterDistribution
{
public:   char district, trace;  
public:  int random_num; 

public : LetterDistribution(){}
     public: LetterDistribution(char dis)
    {
        district = dis;
        trace = 'Z';
    }

public: string LetterNumbers()
{

    random_num = rand();
     string letter_no  ( district + " " + random_num);
    return letter_no;
    }
};

int main()
{
srand(time(0));
    cout << "Enter district\n"<<endl;
    char dis ;
    cin >> dis;
    LetterDistribution ld(dis);
    cout << ld.LetterNumbers();
    return 0;}
```

**I am getting error in second last line inside main "cout << ld.LetterNumbers();". I am new to c++ , I have been working on C# earlier. I shall be thankful if someone could help me .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues in `LetterNumbers` function:

1. You can't add to string a number, you should convert the number to string first. you can do so by `std::to_string(random_num)`
2. You can't start concatenate string with a character, since character is like number in c++, and adding anything to number is a number. You should start from a `string`, even an empty one.

#### So the whole function can be something like:

```
string LetterNumbers()
{
  random_num = rand();
  string letter_no  ( std::string("") + district + " " + std::to_string(random_num));
  return letter_no;
}
```

Another issues: (but not errors!)

- in c++ you can specify `public:` once, and everything after it is still `public`, until you change it. same thing for `private` and `protected`.
- instead of  `<stdio.h>` you should use `<cstdio>` which is the c++ wrapper for the c header.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help . It works perfectly now.